# How to run a Sdl Tridion develop WebSite on localhost

Tags: publishing

I am trying to develop a website on Sdl Tridion. I have created pages for my web site and i run this pages by click on preview button but i want to run these pages like a webSite on my local host .How can i do this.

When I click on publish button, i don't see any target type. So How can i create a target type ?

Answer (score 3):

### How to Configure a Target Type and Publication Target?

1. Using the Content Manager Explorer, click on the `Administration` Tab
2. Select `Target Types` and Click `Show Target Types`
3. Now click on `Target Types` and select `New Target Type`
4. Name the target type as `"Development"` and click `Save and Close`
5. Click on `Publication Targets` and select `Show Publication Targets`
6. Now click on `Publication Targets` -> `New Publication Target`
7. Fill in the following settings and values:

   - Name: Development Target
   - Description: Development Target
   - Target Language: REL OR (As per your setup)
   - Default Code Page: Unicode (UTF-8)
   - Click on "Add" on the lower left corner and enter the destination information:

     - Destination Name: Development Server
     - Protocol: (As per your setup)
     - Login / Password (anything)
     - Url: `http://localhost:8080/COMPANYNAME/httpupload`

       - Click on the `Publication` tab
     - Select your `publications` from the list of "Allowed Publications"
     - Click `Add` button
     - Select `Development Target Type` from the list of "Allowed Target Types"
     - Click `Save and Close`

Now select the page and publish to the development target.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this article

https://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/howto_iis_deployer.aspx

it'd definitely help if you are developing a .Net site